# Consequences of expired password?

Tags: linux, password

What exactly are the consequences of an expired password on Linux/Unix?

Can the account still be used to run non-interactive stuff like software running as daemon?

What is the difference between a locked account and an account with expired password?

Answer (score 2):

[this nixCraft page](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-locking-an-account/) describes *Linux Locking An Account*

An account with expired password can be used for non-interactive stuff like running a daemon / using `cron` etc.

*ssh public key based authentication* might be a difference between a locked account and an account with expired password (**depend on the configuration - on each case**).

When the account is being locked:

- the possibility to login using ssh public key should be disabled.
- Also, the shell might be changed from valid shell (e.g. `/bin/bash` to invalid shell (e.g. `/bin/false`)

When the account password is expired, it might be possible to login using ssh public key.

According to 
[7 Examples to Manage Linux Password Expiration and Aging Using chage](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/chage-linux-password-expiration-and-aging):

> In some cases when the password is expired the user is 
>   forced to change password after expiry date (instead of locking the
>   account):
>
> If the password expiry date reaches and user doesn’t change their
>   password, the system will force the user to change the password before
>   the login as shown below.
>
> ```
> $ ssh dhinesh@testingserver
> dhinesh@testingserver's password:
>
> You are required to change your password immediately (password aged)
> WARNING: Your password has expired.
> You must change your password now and login again!
> Changing password for dhinesh
> (current) UNIX password:
> Enter new UNIX password:
> Retype new UNIX password:
> ```
>
> In some cases force the user account to be locked after X number of
>   inactivity days
>
> Typically if the password is expired, users are forced to change it
>   during their next login. You can also set an additional condition,
>   where after the password is expired, if the user never tried to login
>   for 10 days, you can automatically lock their account using option -I
>   as shown below. In this example, the “Password inactive” date is set
>   to 10 days from the “Password expires” value.   Once an account is
>   locked, only system administrators will be able to unlock it.
>
> ```
> # chage -I 10 dhinesh
>
> # chage -l dhinesh
> Last password change                                    : Apr 23, 2009
> Password expires                                        : May 03, 2009
> Password inactive                                       : May 13, 2009
> Account expires                                         : May 31, 2009
> Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
> Maximum number of days between password change          : 10
> Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7
> ```

Comment: Hi, can It cause running java process stopped or killed ?

Comment: no, password expiry won't impact non-interactive programs